# Stopping a Javascript timer function from running multiple times after using an 'in viewport' function to call it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, timer, viewport

Creating a website with a timer that counts up once the div is scrolled into view. The problem I'm having is that scrolling away starts the timer again, and I'd like the final value that the timer reaches to remain until the page is reloaded.

I've tried using 'event.handled' and '$.Callbacks("once")' but neither seem to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated - code below!

```
$(allInView);
$(window).scroll(allInView);

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return elemBottom <= docViewBottom && elemTop >= docViewTop;
}

function allInView() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($("#column4"))) {
    /// when 'column4' IS being 'viewed', the timers then begin

    jQuery(function ($) {
      $(".timer").countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 183,
        speed: 1000,
        refreshInterval: 50,
        onComplete: function (value) {
          console.debug(this);
        },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want the counter to keep going once the element is first scrolled to and never to stop regardless of what happens after that?

Comment: Not quite; I'd like the timer to reach it's final value (183) once the div is in view, and then remain at that value until the page is reloaded (then the "animation" will begin again.

Comment: Ok but lets say it was scrolled out of view what should happen then?

Comment: Then it would remain at the final value (i.e. it doesn't count up again if it's scrolled BACK into view).

Comment: Ok I thought what you wanted was for the value to only count up while in view and stop counting if it went out of view then resume if it came back into view again. Anyways the answer below has the right idea for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable to check if the timer is already started.

```
let lockTimer = false;

 function allInView () {
     // Exits conditions to avoid to restart the timer
     if (lockTimer || !isScrolledIntoView(...)) {
          return;
     }
     
     lockTimer = true; // block timer launch
     JQuery(...);
 }
```

Comment: I'm noticing now that when the page is reloaded, the timer no longer works and is stuck at the final value - will I have to store the value in localstorage to get around this or is there a workaround?

Comment: You reload the page dynamically ? Refresh will clean the memory except if you do some asynchronous loading or refresh.
So probably you store the final value somewhere ? If it's dynamically reloaded, you have to reset lockTimer to false on a function which have lockTimer in his scope.